# Save Empscripten webGL canvas as image in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, emscripten

I have an Emscripten-driven webGL canvas that I need to save as an image from a Javascript handler. Let's say there's a simple JS "Save" button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Exporter = {
    preRun: [],
    postRun: [],
    save: function() {
    var c=Module.canvas;
    var d=c.toDataURL("image/png");
    var w=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
    w.document.write("<img src='"+d+"' alt='from canvas'/>");
    }
};
</script>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="Exporter.save()" />
```

By default, the webGL context has preserveDrawingBuffer set to false, so the resulting image is blank.

For the image to show the rendered webGL scene, I need to add `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` to the attributes passed in the getContext call inside my compiled Empscripten code. I can do this by hand editing the compiled empscripten js code; the resulting image is then correct, but I'd like to avoid this hack - I'd have to do it after each recompile.

Is there and easier and cleaner way to add `preserveDrawingBuffer` to the `webGLContextAttributes` from outside? i.e. as a compile option for `emcc`, some SDL parameter inside the C code or from Javascript in the hosting page?

**UPDATE**
See below for the solution; unrelated issue I encountered was that the saved image had lower bit depth and anti-aliased lines looked pretty bad. Using `c.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" )` solved that.

Comment: I don't know Emscripten at all ; let alone for webgl, but a better way to export your webgl canvas is to wait the next render loop, and call toDataURL before releasing the current js thread. The drawing buffer will still be there, and you'll improve perfs compared to `preserveDrawingBuffer` option.

Comment: @Kaiido The problem with the approach you suggested is that in my case I'm not rendering all the time @ fixed framerate but only after getting new input events. The Javascript button to save the image can be pressed at any time. So I'd have to first force the canvas to redraw, then from the canvas render code (C) call another Javascript function to capture the buffer before end of frame. Not impossible, but I'd rather take the perf hit for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, all of emscripten and all of it's libraries are open source so you can just go change them.

In particular copy `library_gl.js` to your project folder and then remove `-lGL` and add `--js-library library_gl.js` to your build script, you can then hack your local `library_gl.js` to do whatever you want.

Otherwise I don't know SDL at all but you can just get the context yourself before your call the emscripten code. A canvas can only have one context, if you call `getContext` again for the same type of context you'll get the same context. In other words if your JavaScript creates the context first the emscripten code will get the same context

so this should work

```
 theCanvasElement.getContext("webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});

 ... now execute emscripten and have it use `theCanvasElement`
```

If you can't even do that you can override `getContext`

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (function(oldGetContextFn) {
  return function(type, attrs) {
    attrs = attrs || {};
    if (type === "webgl") {
      attrs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
    }
    return oldGetContextFn.call(this, type, attrs);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext));
```

Comment: Yeah getting the context before emscripten does and giving it the parameters I want seems like a reasonable idea, I'll try that. Still a hack, but at least I'd only have to do it once.

Comment: I'm not sure why you consider it a "hack". If you want to solve it at an SDL level you'd probably need to submit a patch to the SDL library to add some [construction flags](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags) or else submit a patch to emscripten to add some other emscripten only C++ exposed api to force certain flags.

Comment: didn't mean that offensively, just feels like it, probably because it relies on it being unchanged 2nd time getContext is called. Maybe it's just the API semantics, there should be a createContext call?

Comment: You will need to change `apply` to `call` here to make the getContext override work. That or use `oldGetContextFn.apply(this, [type, attrs])`.